# Show that $a_{k-1}a_{k+1}\le a_k^2$ where $P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k X^k$ is a real polynomial with real roots, and $0<k<n$

Tags: polynomials, alternative-proof

the question is in the title.

I know that this is a direct consequence of Newton's inequalities but I'm looking for a proof without using it. A hint was given to solve it :

Show that

> $$ P'^2 - P''P\ge 0$$

To show the given identity, let 
$$P(X) = \lambda\prod_{k=0}^{r} (X-\alpha_k)^{m_k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k$$
The identity :
$$ \dfrac{P'}{P} = \sum \dfrac{m_k}{X-\alpha_k}$$
Shows that $\dfrac{P'}{P}$ is decreasing, but :
$$ \left(\dfrac{P'}{P}\right)' = \dfrac{P''P - P'^2}{P^2}$$
Therefore, $P''P - P'^2\le 0$

To prove that $a_{k-1}a_{k+1}\le a_k^2$ for $0< k<n$, I don't really know how to start. I thought of using Vieta's formulas to express $a_{k-1}a_{k+1}$ and $a_k^2$ but I don't think it will really help me use the fact that $P'^2 - P''P\ge 0$. Any thoughts ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: So the degree is at least 2?

Comment: @greedoid, if the degree is strictly less than 2, there is nothing to proof as the interval $[1, n-1]$ is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution :

Let $$P(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_kX^k$$ $$Q(X) = (P'^2 - P''P)(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n-2} c_kX^k$$

The first observation is that $c_0 = a_1^2 - 2a_0a_2$. Therefore, if $P$ has real roots, $Q(0)\ge 0$ so that $a_1^2\ge 2a_0a_2$. if $a_0a_2<0$, $a_1^2\ge a_0a_2$, otherwise, $a_0a_2\le 2a_0a_2\le a_1^2$ and the result follows for $k=1$.

For other values of $k$, apply the same reasoning to $P^{(k-1)}$ which also has real roots :

Let $P^{(k-1)} = \sum_{j=0}^{n-k+1} c_j X^j$. We know that $c_1^2\ge 2c_0c_2$.

But $c_0 =(k-1)!\cdot a_{k-1}$, $c_1 = k!\cdot a_k$ and $c_2 =(k+1)!a_{k+1}/2$. So that :
$$ k!^2a_k^2\ge (k-1)!(k+1)! a_{k-1}a_{k+1}$$
$$ \implies ka_k^2\ge (k+1)a_{k-1}a_{k+1}$$
$$ \implies a_k^2\ge \dfrac{k+1}{k} a_{k-1}a_{k+1}$$
And the result follows.